# creating loop to ignore repeatative task otherwise procedure too large error showing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge macro where I need to call lots of text files(7 folders and each folder contains 142 text files) with different file name. I dont know how to create loop to insert those files one by one but I wrote some code and while running that "Procedure too Large" error is coming. I am aware that excel can only takes maximum 64kb. The task is same for every worksheet though I am using only 4 sheets in a workbook meaning calling a text file first then filtering the datas and putting those in different sheet in the same workbook. Can anyone help me to make the program small and handy to run and get rid from that "Procedure too large" error. The code is simple but repetitive. Please help me.

Regards,
Pinaki

Comment: Post the code that you have so far, and this will help us to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\Syslog\2016-05-02\2016-05-02\SyslogCatchAll2016-05-02.txt.002", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "SyslogCatchAll2016-05-02.txt"

Comment: Hi Davy..The code is loo long to post here. However I have posted only the first few lines. This is how I am adding those text files one by one. First Inserting the text file in sheet1 in starting from A2 because  I need to put caption in row 1.then after filtering I am putting those filtered data in sheet 2. from sheet 2 I am filtering again for "High" and "Low" values datas and putting those in sheet 3.and also deleting the datas from sheet1 and 2. this step I need to perform for all 7X142 text files whose names are different. Hope I made u understand my pain area. Please help me to do this.

Comment: If you don't post your complete code, I'm not going to help you, past recommending that you deal with the loading of the text files one-by-one, dealing with them, tidying, up, before moving on to the next one. As you have found out, you cannot load thousands of text files into Excel and expect to not run out of resources.

Comment: What Davy is saying is that you can edit the code into your question